# Ajax request in a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with jquery to build a response box (ajax).

Send request with ajax call and wait for the json response and use the response and show a info box.

JSON returned:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // disable the form submit
    e.preventDefault();
    //Button click event
    $("#operation").click(function(e){
        //Disabling button
        $("#operation").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        // get the input data
        var input = $("#nameImport").val();
        //Perform POST for triggering long running operation
        $.get('update', {
            name: input
        }, function(data){
            onSuccessImport(data);
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem i see is that the `e.preventDefault()` should go inside the `click` handler..

```
//Button click event
$("#operation").click(function(e){
    // disable the form submit
    e.preventDefault();
```

---

and a more generic comment is that you should use `.prop` to fiddle with DOM properties (*instead of `.attr`*)
so use

```
$("#operation").prop('disabled', true);
```